# webViewDidFinishLoad() does not appear to be running in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, web, webview

I have a view controller for a webview, setup through **[KINWebBrowser](https://github.com/dfmuir/KINWebBrowser)**.

I've tried several ways to get these methods to execute:

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    print("Strat Loading")
}
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    print("Finish Loading")
}
func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
    print(error?.localizedDescription)
}
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    super.webViewDidFinishLoad(webView)
    print("Finish Loading 2")
}
```

But nothing seems to be working.

My class definition seems normal: `class WebBrowserViewController: KINWebBrowserViewController, NavigationProtocol {`

But no matter what I do - override func or not, no logger or print statement I put in these functions seems to be executed.

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to create an event that will listen to when all of the web content is loaded so I can stop having a loading spinner appear.

EDIT: Adding delegate information:

When I have tried to add a delegate to viewDidLoad():

```
webView.delegate = self
```

I have gotten the following error:

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)'
```

This is my viewDidLoad() without the delegate setting:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pointsNavigationItem = addPointsButtonToNavigation()

    self.showsURLInNavigationBar = false
    self.showsPageTitleInNavigationBar = false;

    self.tintColor = UIColor.navText

    self.barTintColor = .navBackground

}
```

I'm not sure that KinWebBrowser does delegation the same way?

Added the `KINWebBrowserDelegate` to the class definition and added the following methods:

```
func webBrowser(_ webBrowser: KINWebBrowserViewController!, didFailToLoad URL: URL!, error: Error!) {
    print("DEBUG 5")

}

func webBrowserViewControllerWillDismiss(_ viewController: KINWebBrowserViewController!) {
    print("DEBUG 1")
}

func webBrowser(_ webBrowser: KINWebBrowserViewController!, didStartLoading URL: URL!) {
    print("DEBUG 2")

}

func webBrowser(_ webBrowser: KINWebBrowserViewController!, didFinishLoading URL: URL!) {
    print("DEBUG 3")

}

func didChangeValue<Value>(for keyPath: KeyPath<WebBrowserViewController, Value>) {
    print("DEBUG 4")

}
```

None of the debugs are getting called in the log.

Comment: Have you set the delegate for your web view?

Comment: I’m brand new to Swift development and I’m not sure quite how to set a delegate. I tried to do webView.delegate = self and it said that it was ambiguous.

Comment: I tried to set webView.delegate = self inside viewDidLoad() when I got that error.

Comment: You need to update your question with more details about your issue setting the delegate. Once you get that set, the method you've already posted will be called.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: FYI, the only other thing left that I had to do was self.delegate = self

Answer (score 1):

Those are the UIWebView delegate methods, however from the [KINWebBrowser page](https://github.com/dfmuir/KINWebBrowser) you should probably be using the KINWebBrowserDelegate protocol

- (void)webBrowser:(KINWebBrowserViewController *)webBrowser didStartLoadingURL:(NSURL *)URL;
- (void)webBrowser:(KINWebBrowserViewController *)webBrowser didFinishLoadingURL:(NSURL *)URL;
- (void)webBrowser:(KINWebBrowserViewController *)webBrowser didFailToLoadURL:(NSURL *)URL withError:(NSError *)error;

Comment: Could you show a more direct code example? I'm relatively new to Swift development and not quite sure how to implement this. Do I do this in my WebBrowserViewController class, or elsewhere?

Comment: I'm just not understanding the implementation here. I tried this: KINWebBrowserDelegate = self and it isn't working. I'm not totally sure what I'm reading here.

Comment: Looking closer it seems that you are subclassing the KINWebBrowserViewController was that your intention? From the documentation on that library it just shows using it directly instead of subclassing. That might be part of where I am confused. When creating the view controller you would immediately set the delegate on it to your handler. Without a more complete vision of your code it might be difficult to comment further.